# Awk/sed replace in each line with previous string in the line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file `test.txt` like this (but containing many more lines)

```
/foo/bar/how hello
/foo/bar/are hello
/foo/bar/you hello
```

I want to get this output:

```
/foo/bar/how how
/foo/bar/are are
/foo/bar/you you
```

I have tried this:

```
while read line
do
bla=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d"/" | cut -f1 -d" ")
sed -i "s/hello/$bla/"
done <test.txt
```

But the output is:

```
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
```

When I provide the filename (`while read line; do bla=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d"/" | cut -f1 -d" "); sed -i "s/hello/$bla/" test.txt ; done <test.txt`), I get this:

```
/foo/bar/how how
/foo/bar/are how
/foo/bar/you how
```

I would like to replace on each line some constant pattern by a pattern appearing before on the same line and that changes from line to line. Any idea on how I could do that (using sed or awk)? Many thanks!

Comment: You need to provide file as input to sed on the right of `sed -i "s/hello/$bla/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's~\([^/]*\) .*~\1 \1~' file
/foo/bar/how how
/foo/bar/are are
/foo/bar/you you
```

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned in the other answer, could you explain this a bit? If I want to adapt it to some other string :)

Comment: sed doesn't match on strings. If you want to match on strings then you should use awk. I'm not being facetious - that's a very important lesson to learn. The given script searches for a regexp that starts with a sequence of non-/ characters (and captures the sub-string matching that RE segment) followed by a blank character then anything else and replaces that whole matching string with the captured sub-string then a blank then the captured sub-string again. I'm using `~` instead of the more common `/` to separate the script segments to avoid having to escape the `/` inside the regexp.

Comment: OK and I really want to be based on pattern --> I edit my post!

Comment: Avoid using the word `pattern` on it's own as it's highly ambiguous - just say what you mean: `string` or `regexp` or `globbing pattern` or something else. The edit to your question is unclear but sounds like you're going off on a tanget. Don't create a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478). You asked a specific question, you got answers to your specific question, now just select an answer to accept and if you have a followup question then post a new question using clear, concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Oh, and make sure your sample input and any strings you want to match on or replace with contain blanks and regexp metacharacters and backreference metacharacters and sed delimiters (`/`) and anything else you think might be problematic if they can occur in your real data. Also make sure to include lines that do not match your search criteria too. Make the sample worst-case, not best possible, rainbows and butterflies case or you'll get an answer that only works for that!

Comment: thanks for your time explaining this! I posted another question with more details in it on the "acceptable answers"

Comment: But you didn't listen to what I said so your new question has no better example and just a few ambiguous, partial acceptance criteria. See the comment I left under [your new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39275121/1745001)

Answer (score 2):

Below `awk` solution might help

```
awk  '{$2=$1;sub(/.*\//,"",$2)}1' test.txt
```

**Ouput**

```
/foo/bar/how how
/foo/bar/are are
/foo/bar/you you
```

**Notes**

- By default `awk` fields are whitespace separated so, you have two fields ie `$1` and `$2`.
- First assign the first field of every record to second ie `$2=$1`
- Then, in the second field, strip the the part till the last `/` using `sub(/.*\//,"",$2)`.
- `1` at the end is the simplest of `awk` command which prints each record.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's~\(.*/\)\([^ ]*\) .*~\1\2 \2~' test.txt
/foo/bar/how how
/foo/bar/are are
/foo/bar/you you
```

Use the `-i` option to edit the file *in place*:

```
sed -i 's~\(.*/\)\([^ ]*\) .*~\1\2 \2~' test.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `s`: substitute
- `\(.*/\)\`: any character up to last `/`
- followed by `\([^ ]*\)`: any non-space character followed by a space

Using backreference, the strings that matches the pattern are replaced with : first group (`/foo/bar/`)  followed by repeated second group (the word after last `/` : `how`, `are` or `you`).

Comment: Thanks @Kenavoz! Could you explain your command a bit? `sed` is a bit obscure to me ;)