# Awk replace string in line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

NOTE:
This question looks like a [previously posted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273660/awk-sed-replace-in-each-line-with-previous-string-in-the-line/39273912#39273912), but as mentioned in the comments, it turned out to be a [chameleon question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) 
I accepted the answer, and I'm posting here the same problem but with slightly different "solution conditions".

---

I have a file `test.txt` like this (but containing many more lines)

```
/foo/bar/how /SOME_TEXT_HERE/hello
/foo/bar/are hello/SOME_OTHER_TEXT
/foo/bar/you hello
```

I want to get this output:

```
/foo/bar/how /SOME_TEXT_HERE/how
/foo/bar/are are/SOME_OTHER_TEXT
/foo/bar/you you
```

I have tried this:

```
while read line
do
bla=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d"/" | cut -f1 -d" ")
sed -i "s/hello/$bla/" test.txt
done <test.txt
```

But the output is:

```
/foo/bar/how /SOME_TEXT_HERE/how
/foo/bar/are how/SOME_OTHER_TEXT
/foo/bar/you how
```

**NOTE**:

I would like the solution to:

1. allow me to define a variable (here, `bla`) that I will define manually and differently from one file to the other (so not using sthg like basic field position), but using `cut` or other command as in my example)
2. replace a specific string somewhere else in the line by this variable (so not a field position like `$2`, but really something like `s/hello/$bla`)

I'm not sure of this is possible though (obviously I don't know how to do this by myself...), but thanks for your time trying! :)

Comment: You didn't take the advice I gave you in your previous question. Your sample input is still the sunny day, rainbows and butterflies one you had before so, for example, there's still no lines that do NOT contain `hello`, no lines that contain it multiple times in the line (`/foo/hello/how hello`), no lines that contain it as part of the last field (`/foo/bar/how chellogram`) or RE metacharacters, or blanks, or any of the dozen other things that you need to cover in your sample input or the solutions you get will fail when they occur in your real input. **THINK** about and show the worst case.

Comment: Please post a [\[ mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: here are 3 hints 1. `echo "str" | sed 's/t/T'` 2. http://grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html (please read a `sed` tutorial) . 3. you don't need your complex `$(echo ... | cut | cut )`. That is very inefficient, especially for a large file. Also... what ED and sjsam said! Good luck.

Comment: @Ed Morton I edited it. This is the worst case that I could have in my data.

Comment: @Ed morton I just edited my previous comment. In any case, thanks for having taken some time to explain me all of this!

Answer (score 12):

```
awk '{sub(/are hello/,"are are")sub(/you hello/,"you you")}1' file

/foo/bar/how /SOME_TEXT_HERE/hello
/foo/bar/are are/SOME_OTHER_TEXT
/foo/bar/you you
```

Comment: why use 1 in the end of awk command?

Comment: @shashankarora Because if you don't print the output, there is no output. `1` is a shorthand for "print the current input line". (The general structure of an Awk script  is a sequence of _condition_ `{` _actions_ `}` pairs; both of them are optional, which means do nothing. If the condition is missing, the action is taken unconditionally. If the action is missing, the default action is to print the current input record. So `1` is a condition which is always true, and so the result is that the line is printed unconditionally. This is a very common Awk FAQ.)

Comment: (If you wanted to be cute, `"print, always"` would also evaluate as a condition which is always true; but the common idiom is simply `1`.)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is super-easy using `sed`

```
$ sed -E <file '
s/(how.*)hello/\1how/
s/(you.*)hello/\1you/
s/(are.*)hello/\1are/'
/foo/bar/how /SOME_TEXT_HERE/how
/foo/bar/are are/SOME_OTHER_TEXT
/foo/bar/you you
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { old="hello"; lgth=length(old) }
    s = index($0,old) {     # yes, that is an assignment =, not a comparison ==
        n = split($1,f,"/")
        $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) f[n] substr($0,s+lgth)
    }
    { print }
' test.txt
/foo/bar/how /SOME_TEXT_HERE/how
/foo/bar/are are/SOME_OTHER_TEXT
/foo/bar/you you
```

I'm only using string functions and avoiding using any `*sub()` function so that it'll work even if the strings involved contain regexp or backreference metachars.

It would match `hello` mid-string (e.g. in `chellomedia`) and it'll only match once per line but it'll work robustly for the posted input data format.